# Uploading different jars to Artifactory with gradle

Tags: plugins, gradle, artifactory

Is it possible to conditionally upload jars to artifactory?

I have tried using the Artifactory plugin but that works fine if the case is just to upload a single jar from a build pipeline.

If I also want to upload a test jar, how would that go?

Can I have some configuration specifying which jar should be uploaded? e.g. test jar or the "normal" jar file

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
          from components.java
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    clientConfig.setIncludeEnvVars(true)

    contextUrl = 'https://localhost:8081/artifactory/'
    publish {
        repository {
          repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
          username = "${artifactory_user}"
          password = "${artifactory_user_password}"
        }
        defaults {
           publications('mavenJava')
           publishArtifacts = true
           publishPom = true
           publishIvy = true
        }
     }
    resolve {
      contextUrl = 'https://localhost:8081/artifactory'
      repository {
        repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
        username = "${artifactory_user"
        password = "${artifactory_user_password}"
        maven = true
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: which maven plugin are you using? the older `maven` or newer `maven-publish`?

Comment: The newer one: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin

Comment: You linked to the artifactory plugin, I'm asking about the maven plugin. Artifactory plugin uses either `publications` or `publishconfigs` depending on which maven plugin you're using, to determine what artifacts to publish. If you wanted to publish additional artifacts (like test jar for instance), you just add a new maven publication or publishconfig. I need to know which plugin you're using to give you appropriate instructions. It may help to share your build.gradle.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've added build.gradle to my question now. I'm using publications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish classes from your test SourceSet (`src/test/` by default), you first need to define a task to create the testJar:

```
task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from sourceSets.test.output
}
```

Then add it to your publications

```
publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java

        artifact testJar {
            classifier "test"
        }
    }
}
```

Since you're already publishing `publications('mavenJava')` from artifactory, you do not have to make any changes there.

Comment: that's great RaGe, thank you very much. I have one last question left, is it possible to conditionally do the upload? E.g. if sometimes I want to upload only my test jar on some occasions

Comment: I imagine you should be able to wrap `artifact testJar{...}` in an `if (condition){...}` but I haven't tested that myself.